# Bootstrap Carousel: Need to auto cycle once but next and previous buttons should loop through slides

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

To loop back and forth between images, I am using data-attribute "wrap"

```
data-wrap="true"
```

This works fine for me, but I also want to auto load the cycle only once and then it should stop. For that if I do:

```
data-wrap="false"
```

It will do the trick. **But the problem is that I want the carousel to cycle only once on page load and then stop while still being able to loop back and forth between images with next and previous buttons**

**.i.e.**

when slider reaches it's last image, further click on next should turn the first image and similarly for 1st image, if click on previous it should turn on the last image.

I did try to add the **data-attribute "interval"** but it also stops the auto cycle.

This is what I have tried so far and which is not working for me.

```
  var slide_counter   = 0,
        slider_1        = jQuery('#carousel-example-generic1'),
        slider_2        = jQuery('#carousel-example-generic2');

    slider_1.on('slide.bs.carousel', function(){
        slide_counter++;

        if(slide_counter == 3){

            slider_1.carousel({
                interval: false
            });

            slider_2.carousel({
                interval: false
            });
            //slider_1.attr('data-interval', 'false');
            //slider_2.attr('data-interval', 'false');
        } // end if
    });
```

**2nd thought:**

```
var slider_1        = jQuery('#carousel-example-generic1'),
    slider_2        = jQuery('#carousel-example-generic2');

if(slider_1.carousel(2)){
    jQuery('#carousel-example-generic1, #carousel-example-generic2').carousel({
        interval: false
    });

} // end if
```

Comment: use a listener and check when the slider is on the last image then set the interval to false.

Comment: @JordanD Can you kindly look at the code above and see what mistake I am making?

Comment: Don't keep track of the count yourself: `.carousel(number)`

Cycles the carousel to a particular frame (0 based, similar to an array). http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: I have also tried the other way, can you please look at the 2nd thought of code above.

Comment: if you set up a bootply i will work on it.

Answer (score -1):

I would try something like the following. I included comments for the logic.

```
    //listener for after slide
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
   //Each slide has a .item class to it, you can get the total number of slides like this
    var totalItems = $('.item').length;

  //find current slide number
    var currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;

  //if slide number is last then stop carousel
  if(totalItems == currentIndex){
        $('.carousel').carousel({
          interval: false
    })
  }

})
```

Comment: It seems like function to set interval to false does not work within listener function, though if I try it outside, it does work but then it's useless :(

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question but for others looking at this post to find THE answer:

```
var $carousel = $('#myCarousel');
$carousel.on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    if($(e.target).find('.item.active').is(':last-child')) {
        $carousel.carousel('pause');
    }
});
```

Just keep the `wrap` option `true` to make it work.

Comment: Why downvoting, this was implemented in our project and it works :)